# selecting records that are 3 days from expiring datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table that contains a `datetime timestamp`. What I am looking for is to select records that are exactly 3 days from the 30 day expiration based on the `datetime timestamp`.

Here is what I have so far although I don't think it is correct:

```
    SELECT jobs.*,occupations.title
    FROM jobs
    LEFT JOIN occupations on occupations.id = jobs.occupation_id
    WHERE DATE_ADD(jobs.`date_created`,INTERVAL 27 DAY) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: Does that not work for sure or you just `think` it wont?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky It does not seem to be working.

Comment: You will need to lose the time part of the jobs.date_created if it has one.